# how to get the dropdown selected default values in another div as a simple text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have dropdown to select current month and year, i am getting the values properly.

now i need to pass that values into some other div

**how to get the dropdown selected default values in another div as a simple text??**

it should change if selected values change

Fiddle to describe

http://jsfiddle.net/k1v7ga49/1/

Dropdowns

```
<select name="one" class=" select1" id="ddlYear">
    <option value="-1">Select Year</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
</select>   

<select name="two" class="select2" id="ddlMonth">
    <option value="-1">Select Month</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
var d = new Date(),
month = d.getMonth() + 1,
year = d.getFullYear();
$('.select2 option:eq(' + month + ')').prop('selected', true);
$('.select1').val(year);

$('.select2').on('change', function () {
    var selectedYear = ($("option:selected", $('.select1')).text());
    if (selectedYear != "Select Year") {
        selectedMonth = ($("option:selected", this).text());
        loadData(selectedYear, selectedMonth);
    }
});
```

i want selected values in this div (in #monthValue)

```
<div class="placer"> Current timeperiod is :
    <div id="monthValue"></div>
</div>
```

MY EXPECTED RESULT: Current timeperiod is :2014 OCTOBER

Comment: `$(#monthValue').html(selectedYear + ' ' + selectedMonth);`

Comment: So you want to see default values on page load or on selectbox change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.select2, .select1').on('change', function () {
    var selectedYear = $('.select1').val();
    if (selectedYear != "Select Year") {
        selectedMonth = $('.select2').val();
        $('#monthValue').text(selectedYear + ' ' + selectedMonth)
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

And to make the displayed values inline add this to the CSS

```
#monthValue {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/k1v7ga49/4/

Comment: @ Spokey, IT IS NOT UPDATING IN FIDDLE ??

Comment: @ spookey: i want to update the default values in div expected is Current timeperiod is :2014 OCTOBER

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa add `#monthValue{display:inline-block;}` to the CSS

Comment: @ spookey: please check my edited comment sorry for not clear question

Comment: @ Spokey, it is working please update the answer so i can make it right answer , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If i got you right you have to just use `.text()`

```
$('#monthValue').text(selectedYear + '  ' + selectedMonth);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1v7ga49/3/)

Comment: @ Y.Puzyrenko, IT IS NOT UPDATING IN FIDDLE

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa first of all, turn of the caps lock, the second it's updating, check once more.

Comment: Y.Puzyrenko sorry for the capslock, my requirement is default value in div, sorry for not clear. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made a jsbin for ya, at http://jsbin.com/kidujoxidoku/1/edit

I feel as if you were making your checking of each  `select` element's value too complicated. Simply using the jQuery's `val()` function should be all you need.

The code is also below for reference.

```
var d = new Date(),
month = d.getMonth() + 1,
year = d.getFullYear(),
loadData = function(year, month) {
    $('.placer #monthValue').html(year + " " +month);
};

$('.select2 option:eq(' + month + ')').prop('selected', true);
$('.select1').val(year);



$('.select2').on('change', function () {
    var selectedYear = $('.select1').val(), selectedMonth;
    if (selectedYear != "Select Year") {
        selectedMonth = $(this).val();
        loadData(selectedYear, selectedMonth);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use check of existance of selected data. This is working code, so you can just copy/paste ;)

```
var d = new Date(),
month = d.getMonth() + 1,
year = d.getFullYear();
$('.select2 option:eq(' + month + ')').prop('selected', true);
$('.select1').val(year);

$('.select2').on('change', function () {
  if ($(".select1 option:selected") && $(this).find("option:selected"))
    var selectedYear = $(".select1").val();
    selectedMonth = $(this).val();
    $('#monthValue').text(selectedYear + ' ' + selectedMonth);
  }
});
```